# Dependencies with tailwind that are installed in Create react app

Tags: tailwind-css

why dont we now install lib such as postcss and autoprfixers with tailwind css on CRA

Now If I go to Tailwind docs for installtion of tailwind into my react app which has been
created with CRA

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

```
npm install -D tailwindcss
npx tailwindcss init
```

but if my memory serves right it used to be

```
npm install -D tailwindcss autoprefixer postcss
npx tailwindcss init
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. According to [this commit](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss.com/commit/e06877b28c728a5f38cbeecce6ba77016b9d4522) Tailwind has changed the installation guide.

They did this to discourage using CRA more since there are better tools out there to create a React app. For example [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/)

From the [Install Tailwind CSS with Create React App](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app)

> Create React App does not support custom PostCSS configurations

When using Vite the [Tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite) do say to install `postcss` and `autoprefixer`

```bash
npm create vite@latest my-project -- --template react
cd my-project
```

```bash
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init -p
```